# Rails3 routes problem: undefined method `resources'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have installed Rails version 3.0.3, and now I have problems with my routes.rb file.

```
routes.rb:1: undefined method `resources' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

Where the problem can be?

```
resources :plains
```

That's all in my **routes.rb**

Comment: please post the code in your routes.rb file. We can't help if we don't have anything to look at.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that's the entirety of `routes.rb`, you'll need to add a block around it:

```
MyAppName::Application.routes.draw do
   resources :plains
end
```

Answer (score 7):

Given a routes file like this:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  # Put resources here
end
```

You need to declare your resources inside that block, is that what you've done?

Your error saying resources is not a member of object, which leads me to believe you've made that declaration outside this block, as inside this block, you're in the scope of the app's routes, and `resources` is a method of that object.

Full code post would help though.

**edit** given that the error is on line 1 of that file, this is definitely what you've done, place it in the block

Comment: Thank you, but after running scaffold command the routs.rb file was totally empty.

Comment: I don't know why, but it was empty after processing scaffold command