# Trouble with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

So recently I started learning Rails and came upon a tutorial on how to build a Twitter-clone from scratch using Rails. Now I did my research, followed the tutorial to the letter and am on the verge of giving up completely. Following problem: When I run `rails server` in my [project directory](http://github.com/theneonspectre/railsfun) I get an error like this

`config/routes.rb: undefined method resources`

How do I get this to work or what am I doing wrong? When I followed the tutorial and put the `ActionController` class in `config/routes.rb` I get an error saying `NameError`. The link to the tutorial is located in the README of my repo. Help appreciated and please do not downvote or close or delete this question because I really need help!

Comment: Please show the contents of the routes.rb file here, as part of your question.

Comment: ... and does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403230/rails3-routes-problem-undefined-method-resources

Comment: Happy to help. But, you *really* need to add to your question (not in comments) your full error stack trace and your `routes.rb`. Otherwise, there's nothing we can do to help you.

Comment: @jvillian I'm not too sure how to markup a code section tbh.

Answer (score 1):

so the problem in your routes was that you were using depricated functions
try this

```
    resources :posts  
    match ':controller/:action/:id', via: [:get, :post]  
    match ':controller/:action/:id.:format', via: [:get, :post]  
    root :controller => "posts", :action => 'index'
```

also u hadn't given an action to the root method call
hope this helps

Comment: the methods u were using with map. calls are now depricated in rails 5

Comment: P.S. , you should use a better tutorial, most of the methods you have used all across your code are depricated in rails-5. either switch you a lower version of rails or find a better tutorial

Comment: Sorry, I was busy, thx, I'll try the former! :) If tat doesn't work then, I'll just have to do as you suggested.